# How to extract arguments of color spaces and determine brightness of said colors?

Tags: color, options, style, arguments, background

The objective is to produce an automated theme with contrasting colors for `EvaluationNotebook` `FontColor` and `Background`. The following is how I grab those two colors but I do not know how to extract the values that make up the colors:

```
fontcolor = 
  Extract[First[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor]], {2}];
background = 
  Extract[First[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], Background]], {2}]
Head@fontcolor
Head@background
```

1. How to extract arguments from different colors spaces (`RGBColor`, `GrayLevel`, etc.) in general?
2. I imagine that I can probably take the `GrayLevel` cutoff point at .5. A value above is considered light and below dark. But once I have for example all 3 arguments for `RGBColor`, should their maximum values be added up and take the cutoff at halfway maximum which would 1.5?

Comment: If you care about the contrast between colors, take a look at [`LABColor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LABColor.html): The LAB color space is designed to be perceptually uniform. This means that equal amounts of perceived difference between the colors corresponds to equal differences between the components of the color. The `L` component of the color also corresponds to lightness if you specifically care about light/dark. There's also [`ColorDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorDistance.html) to directly compute the perceived distance between colors.

Comment: @LukasLang great tip. i dont know much about combining coordinating color (swatches) for creating eye pleasing themes. it sounds easy to the casual observer. yes the first two or three may be relatively easy but after that the get very difficult because we cant help but to interject bias toward our color preferences. thanks for the tip. im definitly going to try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RGBColor and GrayLevel are just semantic wrappers.

```
FullForm[Orange]
```

`RGBColor[1,0.5,0]`

```
FullForm[Gray]
```

`GrayLevel[0.5]`

So, you can inspect/manipulate them just like other Mathematica expressions.

```
Orange[[2]]
```

`0.5`

```
MySpecialThing @@ Gray
```

`MySpecialThing[0.5]`

> ... should their maximum values be added up ...

You're going to need to define your own semantics for what light and dark mean. One thought is to take the mean:

```
Mean[List @@ Purple]
```

`0.333333`

so maybe that is dark?

Or maybe you use ColorConvert:

```
ColorConvert[Red, GrayLevel]
```

`GrayLevel[0.299]`

and use the same heuristic you're using for grays. There is also ColorDistance, so you could compare to a reference. Or use Hue, which has a brightness argument.

Comment: fantastic tips. GrayLevel is easy to figure out but here i thought there were some fancy algorithms inside the guts of RGBColor. if i had known its just a wrapper i would have done this `Mean[Orange /. RGBColor -> List]`. still your tips are exactly what i needed. you've helped me before, i never forget. thank you.
":

Answer (score 3):

You might try working in the hue, saturation, and brightness color space for this.

Suppose I have a RGB color with red value 0.1, green value 0.8 and blue value 0.7

```
colorRGB = RGBColor[.1, .8, .7]
```

[image]

We can change color space to Hue, Saturation and Brightness (HSB) with:

```
colorHSB = ColorConvert[colorRGB, "HSB"];
```

We can see that `colorHSB` is stored differently then `colorRGB`:

```
FullForm[colorHSB]
```

`Hue[0.4761904761904761,0.875,0.8]`

Where 0.476 is the hue or "color",  0.875 is the saturation (how much of the color), and 0.8 is the brightness (amount of light).

After converting the color space to HSB we can access the hue, saturation, and brightness values directly:

```
{colorHSB[[1]], colorHSB[[2]], colorHSB[[3]]}
```

`{0.47619, 0.875, 0.8}`

Comment: Note that your last step of accessing the HSB values as a list could be more readily achieved with `List @@ colorHSB`. It avoids typing out the explicit part specifications.